# How to find the shortest path inside a blob in a binary image using python?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, numpy-ndarray

I have a binary image (2D NumPy array) with some blobs. For each blob, I want to find the shortest connected path between the leftmost and rightmost coordinates of the blob.

Using  `cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats()` I can obtain information on each label (bbox, pixels belonging to this blob, etc.). This allows obtaining the leftmost and rightmost points for each blob.

Is there any simple way to compute the shortest connected path?

Comment: Question needs some code:
Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How about `SimpleBlobDetector`?

Comment: This is not a common operation, so I doubt you will find it ready-made in OpenCV. You can implement the Dijkstra algorithm yourself, inside the blobs. (There is a distance transform, but that is not enough to trace the path.)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. SimpleBlobDetector  can be useful to detect the blobs, but it cannot  find the shortest path. It seems that I will have to implement Dijkstra myself, as suggested by Yves.